# Grails compile error

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm getting the following error in my Grails app. Grails 1.3.7, Spring Security plugin 2.6 How to solve this? I can still run the app but this is realy bugging me.

```
 Configuring Spring Security UI ...
2011-12-08 09:35:07,701 [main] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [springSecurityCore:1.2.6]: You must provide a configuration attribute
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must provide a configuration attribute
    at SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:538)
    at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
    at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure8_closure14.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:263)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure8_closure14.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure8.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:299)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure8.call(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure8.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:245)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:35)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/Test2
```

Comment: I suggest searching through the spring-security source and finding where the "you must provide a configuration attribute" message is generated (and why). Are you missng entries for your user/role classes in Config.groovy?

Comment: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy#L538

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 1.2.4, but the plugin code in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:538 is referencing the filterChain in your securityConfig (which should now be in your Config.groovy file - unlike the Acegi plugin). As suggested look in the plugin source code. You'll find it in: `~/.grails/1.3.7/projects/{yourproject}/plugins`

This plugin is an awesome, if somewhat complicated beast - get the basics down with the tutorial: [Spring Security Plugin Tutorial](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/23%20Tutorials.html) Then read the docs carefully, it will save you a ton of time.